# Does OpenId support Ajax login?

Tags: ajax, authentication, openid

I plan to use OpenId with my project, it will be cool if I can authenticate the user to openId provider through Ajax. I am not sure weather it is possible?

Comment: This has a fairly clear explanation of the mechanics of OpenId including doing it through AJAX. Just wish they had extended the thorough explanation to the second two modes of operation
http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995171/Introduction

Answer (score 8, accepted):

check this page out --> http://openid-demo.appspot.com/